# Core Data search by word

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data object `Contact`

```
Contact
=======
fullName
```

I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to show a list of contacts.

I now want to add search option that behave as follow:

If user search for the string "**da**", the results should be:

Aaron David
Bert Daniels
Dana
John David

So the search result is **alphabetic** sorted strings that has a **word** starting with "**da**"

I remember watching a WWDC session showing how to create a Word object and store each word independently, but I'm trying to avoid this approach.

So my question is, can I do such a search with my current model structure and some predicate magic, or I must store the fullName as separate words?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
if(searchString.length)
{
    for (NSString* searchStringPart in [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "])
    {
        if([searchStringPart length] > 0)
        {
            [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchStringPart]];
        }
    }

    filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[filterPredicate, [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray]]];
}
```

And for sorting:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = @[sort];
....
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: what is filterPredicate?

Comment: It my is general main filter. In my case: NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deletedServer == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; You don't have to use it and just make an empty predicate.

Comment: but u break the search string to words, I dont need to do it I need to find results by words

Answer (score 0):

You need to use predicate for filtered word by name in your array. Use below:-

```
//Assuming you have store the name in one array
NSArray *names=@[@"Aaron David",@"Bert Daniels",@"Dana",@"John David"];    

//Now use contains in predicate for filtered words 
//On the basis of search string it will filtered accordingly. lets Say yourStringValue=@"on"
NSPredicate *pd=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[CD] %@",yourStringValue];

NSArray *ar=[names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pd];
NSLog(@"%@",ar);
```

Output:-

```
"Aaron David"
```

Comment: I am sure this is not what the OP had in mind. The solution should have returned "Oneida Smith" or "King Ontario" for want of better examples. But certainly not Aaron David.